# How to add with Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have the jquery line that allows me to open.window and access one of HTML file which works great. Please see sample code.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['currentfile'])) { ?>
$("#sourcepreviewout").click(function () {
window.open("<?php $dir = "template/" . trim(file_get_contents("admin/template.txt")) . "/result/";
echo $dir . $_SESSION['currentfile'];
?>", '_blank');
});
<?php } ?>
});
```

I want to add `<iframe>` on window.open, ... how can I write code to add `<Iframe>` with the size of 200px by 200px on window open and show HTML file inside of `<iframe>`!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need for this jQuery. you can do his very easy with Javascript.

```
// Change "src" of iframe with your html Link
var iframe = "<iframe src='https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Window/open' width='200' height='200'></iframe>";

var openWindow = window.open("", "Opened Window", "width=500,height=500,location=no");

openWindow.document.write(iframe);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/06hpd7p7/1/

I think, this is all, what you need